# Yii1 - count before limit and offset with query all

Tags: yii, yii1.x

At the end of the query conditions (the query is a bit long, and the rest of the query is not that important), I have this part:

```
$command->limit($this->pageSize, $this->getOffset());
$records = $command->queryAll();
```

Is it possible to perform count before `$records = $command->queryAll();` without using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can reuse existing command and fetch count using `queryScalar('COUNT(*)')`:

```
$count = (clone $command)->queryScalar('COUNT(*)');
$command->limit($this->pageSize, $this->getOffset());
$records = $command->queryAll();
```